# LaTeX rendering problems in Chrome

Tags: bug, mathjax, google-chrome

I recently asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710452/prove-1222-cdotsn2-n1-choose22n1-choose3/710757?noredirect=1#comment1487519_710757) on the main site. The $\LaTeX$ in one of the answers doesn't render. It isn't a problem with the syntax, it renders on the answerers browser(Firefox). Attached screenshot below[image]

The poster attached a screenshot of his rendering so I could read, so the screenshot of the screenshot is also present, which can be read.

Comment: The question renders fine for me on Chrome 33.0.1750.146 m (under Windows).

Comment: I've deleted here the `%` at the end of `\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k}{1}+2\binom{k}{2}` $$\begin{eqnarray*}
S &:&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{k}{1}+2\binom{k}{2}
=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{k}{1}+2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k}{2} \\
&=&\binom{n+1}{2}+2\binom{n+1}{3} \\
&=&\frac{n\left( n+1\right) \left( 2n+1\right) }{6}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$ With that `%`it didn't render here in this comment box.

Comment: @AméricoTavares yes the modified version renders now.

Comment: @MartinSleziak that could be it. My chrome is ancient. 25.

Comment: @Sabyasachi I will delete the `%` in my answer at the main site. Done.

Comment: @AméricoTavares okay. thanks. rendering perfectly now. :) You can remove the screenshot if you want to.

Comment: @Sabyasachi It's a strange behaviour, because that `%` was at the end of a line.

Comment: @AméricoTavares I know. very weird. Anyway issue resolved now.

Comment: Some browsers remove line breaks, and that appears to be what happened in Chrome, so the comment became the entire rest of the equation, and it didn't render.  Had the line break been retained, you would have had a multi-line error box.